# Session Expiry in AWS Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, openid-connect, amazon-elb

I am using AWS ALB for OIDC authentication, and once authenticated it lands to my backend application where i create a session save it in redis and return the session cookie back to front end.

The front end uses the cookie to commuicate with my backend.

After 10 minutes if the session is expired. Then i want to redirect the page login page.

My question is should i handle the session expiry in my code or does AWS ALB has some intelligence in it to know that my sesion is expired and redirect to logic page.

If i have to explicitly redirect form my code. DO i need to get location header and statu code as 302 as below.

/login is listener in ALB which will authenicate to OIDC

```
            response.getHeaders().setLocation(URI.create("/login"));
            response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FOUND);
```

However, when i redirect to /login. which is path route configred in ALB to authenticate via OIDC. I get 404 0r 400 not found from Oauth provider . Is it because of setting location header am not sure

Answer (score 1):

Your session is handled by your backend services and ALB has no knowledge nor access to it. So, you should also handle session expiration in your code.

Comment: Thank you StefanN, 

However my problem dosent end here.  When i redirect to /login.  which is path route configred in ALB to  authenticate via OIDC.

I get 404 0r 400 not found.  Is it because of setting location header am not sure

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Can you make sure that you are redirecting to https?

Comment: @VIJ Were you able to solve the problem with my answer?